# How to display image stored in variable using the url?

Tags: javascript, jquery, parse-platform

USING PARSE.COM AND THE JAVASCRIPT SDK

With the below code I can get as far as letting the user upload an image from the webpage and storing that as an object in a "file" column in the parse db.

I can store the image details, including the url in the

What i'm unable to do is extract the url back out and display the image on a html page.

I've added the screen shots to show how the data is held in `var profilePhoto` but i'm then unable to make it show on the page using  `$("profile_pic").attr('src',jobApplication[0]);`

What have I overlooked ? I've searched SO and cannot find an relevant question that helps with this.

RESULTS IN INSPECT ELEMENT

> ```
> Arguments[1]0: t.Filecallee: function () {length: 1__proto__: Object user_profile.html:408
> t.File {_name: "tfss-fe809632-ffb8-445c-99f3-1149e4ffdec5-IMG_0047.jpg", _source:
> ```
>
> t.Promise, _previousSave: t.Promise, _url:
>   "http://files.parsetfss.com/0fc5cba8-caf7-4c81-aafc…fe809632-ffb8-445c-99f3-1149e4ffdec5-IMG_0047.jpg",
>   name: function…}_name:
>   "tfss-fe809632-ffb8-445c-99f3-1149e4ffdec5-IMG_0047.jpg"_previousSave:
>   t.Promise_source: t.Promise_url:
>   "http://files.parsetfss.com/0fc5cba8-caf7-4c81-aafc-36390888e497/tfss-fe809632-ffb8-445c-99f3-1149e4ffdec5-IMG_0047.jpg"**proto**:
>   Object

CODE

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var parseAPPID = "XXX";
    var parseJSID = "XXXX";

    //Initialize Parse
    Parse.initialize(parseAPPID,parseJSID);

    $("#fileUploadBtn").on("click", function(e) {

        var fileUploadControl = $("#fileUploader")[0];
        if (fileUploadControl.files.length > 0) {
            var file = fileUploadControl.files[0];
            var name = file.name;
            console.log("here goes nothing...");
            var parseFile = new Parse.File(name, file);
            parseFile.save().then(function() {
                console.log("Woot!");
                console.dir(arguments);
var User = Parse.Object.extend("_User")
var jobApplication = Parse.User.current();

jobApplication.set("ProfilePic", parseFile);
jobApplication.save();



var profilePhoto = jobApplication.get("ProfilePic");
console.log(profilePhoto);
$("profile_pic").attr('src',jobApplication[0]);




            }, function(error) {
                console.log("Error");
                console.dir(error);
            });
        }

    });


});
```

Answer (score 0):

`$("profile_pic")` returns elements with `profile_pic` tag name, which obviously is not the thing you need. Don't see your HTML, but if `profile_pic` is id or class name of your `img` element, this will work if you type `$("#profile_pic")` or `$(".profile_pic")` respectively.